# Pressing own fruits/berries

Tags: cider, fruit

I'm planning to make a berry cider this year and considering using fresh berries (raspberry or blackberry).

Does any body knows basic stats on raspberries or blackberries, like how many pounds do you need to produce 1 gallon of juice? What's the approximate starting gravity of freshly pressed berry juice?

I tried to search through google, but no luck. Lots of recipes with sugar additions for making country wine, but now stats on fresh berries.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would think they would have a similar yield per pound as strawberries.

I juiced 6lb of strawberries for 64oz (1/2 gallon) of juice.

Comment: Do you know the OG of fresh juice? I would assume it makes like 1.060 or something. Also, if it takes about 15lbs of apples for 1 gallon of juice, having 12lbs of berries for 1 gallon would make sense.

Comment: @RedTrigger this juice was 7 brix, 1.028SG

Comment: Strawberries would make 7 brix juice? Wow... Raspberries might be 10-11 or so... they seem to be juicier...

Comment: @RedTrigger yeah, not a lot of sugar in strawberries. At least the variety I used.